# Example of a series, which its square sum converges, but it is not a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Give an example of a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$, in any normed vectorial space, such that $$\sum_{n\ge1}\|x_{n}\|^{2}\le\infty $$
but when you put  $$S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$$
the sequence $\{S_{n}\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence. 
I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: I have found some questions which is like mine, but none of then give me a example! thank you!

Comment: Would you be able to be more specific about what the values $x_i$ are?  Are they numbers? Vectors?  Something else?

Comment: If you really meant $\sum||x_n||\le\infty$ then that conditions says nothing whatever. But you said "absolutely convergent" in the title - if you really meant $\sum||x_n||<\infty$ then there is no such sequence, as you just proved in that other post. ???

Comment: But what is $||x_n||$ ?  So many norms, so little time to guess.

Comment: Now it is clear to me, the harmonic series!!!!!! let $x_{n}=1/n$ Thank you for everybody!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\leq$ means $<$, then $x_n=1/n$ is the standard example.

Comment: This is the right answeer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\|x_n\|$ just means absolute-value and $x_n$ are real numbers:

If the series converges absolutely, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an associated $N$ for which $$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |x_n| < \varepsilon$$

Then for any $m \geq n \geq N$ we have $$|S_n - S_m| = \left| \sum_{p=n}^m x_n \right| \leq \sum_{p=n}^m |x_n| \leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |x_n| < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Sorry @Soke in the summation has a square then you answer is not correct, sorry again in the post I forgot to put the $^2$ ( square )